# Are there any hosts that use openstack?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, cloud-computing, cloud

http://www.openstack.org/

I'm looking for a good cloud hosting company with utility style costs (paying for how much bandwidth, hard disk, cpu is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matthew,

I work for OpenStack and am happy to provide you some guidance on service providers implementing it.

First, it's important to note that there are two OpenStack projects:  Compute and Object Storage.  It sounds like you are looking for Compute, but FWIW on the Object Storage side Rackspace is currently running this code as "Rackspace Cloud Files".  We expect other service providers to implement Object Storage in the coming months.

Regarding Compute, this is actually not yet implemented at Rackspace (or anywhere else), as the code is still being written.  We are going through the process of merging the best of NASA's Nebula cloud code with Rackspace Cloud Servers, and the first release of that code is scheduled for October 21st.  It will be some number of months after that before you will see service providers put it into production, including Rackspace.

I hope this answers your question.  Fee free to follow me on twitter @sparkycollier as well as the project @openstack and also keep up with the latest on the blog openstack.org/blog

Thanks for your interest in our project!

Mark Collier
Chief Community Stacker
@sparkycollier

Comment: What's the status of Compute right now?

Answer (score 1):

As OpenStack was primarily created by [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/index.php), I would think that they would be the one.  There's a long list of other companies arguably "involved" with OpenStack but in terms of a real live cloud provider offering OpenStack based services, AFAIK it's just Rackspace.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I know of Rackspace. Actually, that's how I found out about openstack.

Comment: Just Rackspace so far.  Of course openstack's only been out like 2 months so that's not surprising.